# Label files independently and concurrently in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, data-processing

I have 300 small `csv` files (10-100MB each). I want to treat each file independently. For each row of a file, I want to count occurrences of a column value in the next 20,000 rows, and use that as a label for the row. I am thinking of a job to process these files concurrently to speed this up. Is this something I can do with Spark or should I try to use something different? Most uses of Spark seem to be for treating data as one big dataset and I am not sure if my use case is possible.

```
input: directory of files d

concurrently for each file in d:
  for each row r in file:
    count where r['a'] == x['a'] for x in next 20,000 rows
    add this count as a column 'label' in row r

output: same files, but with extra column 'label'
```

Example (looking ahead 2 rows instead of 20,000):

```
Input: 
file1: [('a':'pen', 'b':'apple'), ('a':'bike', 'b':'apple'), ('a':'pen', 'b':'bike')] 
file2: [('a':'chair', 'b':'apple'), ('a':'chair', 'b':'pen'), ('a':'chair', 'b':'pen')]


Output: 
file1: [('a':'pen', 'b':'apple', 'label': 2), ('a':'bike', 'b':'apple', 'label':0), ('a':'pen', 'b':'pen', 'label':0)] 
file2: [('a':'chair', 'b':'apple', 'label':3), ('a':'chair', 'b':'pen', 'label':0), ('a':'chair', 'b':'pen', 'label':0)]
```

Comment: This seems like something you could do with spark but I am not sure what you are trying to do. Could you please provide a sample input and expected output?